# Sending and receiving large RSA-encrypted cyphers

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, biginteger

I have just finished writing a program which encrypts an integer with the RSA crypto method. I am facing two major issues when scaling this program from being able to transmit just a small integer (around 4 digits so far) to being able to transmit full messages.

Issue #1: How can I get away with showing just the public key? Doesn't my partner need to have n as well as my public key to encrypt a message for me? (Formula below)

> Encryption: F(m,e)=m^e mod n = c, where m is the message, e is the public key, n is the product of the two randomly generated primes and c is the cipher.
>
> Decryption: F(c,d)=c^d mod n = m, where d is the private key.

Issue #2: How can I transmit large messages? The [article](http://doctrina.org/How-RSA-Works-With-Examples.html) I am using as the base for my code touches on encrypting via blocks, but I don't know where to begin with such a thing. From other's questions I have garnered that I should read a file into a byte stream and then encrypt individual bytes with the BigInteger Class, but there is not much detail. How is this done?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623367/rsa-encryption-decryption-using-java

Answer (score 2):

An RSA public key is a pair of numbers: the public exponent and the modulus.

You don't encrypt large messages with RSA; use RSA to encrypt other cryptographic keys.

Your sender should choose a random key for AES, and encrypt a message with that, operating in a suitable mode. Then they will encrypt the AES key with your RSA public key, and send you the AES-encrypted message, and the RSA-encrypted key.

Block cipher modes aren't designed for use with RSA. They are designed for block ciphers like AES and TDEA.